# AppSelfHostBase in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, servicestack

i would like to create a self hosted host in my Xamarin.Forms application. I'm working on a library that targets .NETStandard2, but when I try to create my host i cannot figure out how to get the right reference in order to have AppSelfHostBase available

class ServerHost : AppSelfHostBase

Any help, please?
Thanks in advance
Leonardo

Answer (score 2):

The .NET Standard 2.0 dlls only supports running a [ASP.NET Core AppHost](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore) where the base class is instead:

```
class ServerHost : AppHostBase { ... }
```

But this is only supported for hosting on the .NET Core runtime or [running on the v4.7 .NET Framework](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#run-aspnet-core-apps-on-the-net-framework), not for running on Mono in Xamarin Mobile Apps.

Comment: Any suggestion how to create a selfhosted Web Service in Xamarin?

Comment: @LeonardoZambonelli There was a time when you could run a HttpListener host on Android (never possible in iOS) but trying to do that now fails with can't find System.Web which is not available for Android, so it doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: Thanks. I think i will implement a simple HTTP server using a "normal" socket, and use it using IoC within Xamarin Apps.